# Book about the secret of Delphi oracles and hexagonal patterns

Tags: identification-request

I don't remember the author of this book.

The title/subtitle was something about mystery/secret, Delphi oracles... But since this was a translation, it is quite possible the original title is different.

The book was about strange things and coincidences in the world, hexagonal patterns... I read the book about  13 years ago.
Unfortunately, I do not remember much else and my online searches failed miserably.

I read it in my own language, Bulgarian, but I believe the original language is English.

The author's name was plain - Robert, Tom - something like that. I do not remember much of the book itself but it was telling about finding hexagonal patterns everywhere in nature and lots of other stuff. That is why I would like to reread it - because I have forgotten most of it.

Hopefully, someone here might have read it. :)

PS. It is not [*The Sirius Mystery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirius_Mystery) by Robert Temple and I don't remember any alien references in the book itself.
The book was of "normal" size - i.e., around 300 pages more or less.

PPS. The book is not famous, nor the author.

Comment: This is pretty vague. Please tell us everything else you remember about the book. Did you read it in English? Was it told in the first person? Do you remember any of the strange things that happens?

Comment: I read it in my own language - Bulgarian, but I believe the original language is English. The author's name was plain - Robert, Tom -something like that. I do not remember much of the book itself but it was telling about finding hexagonal patterns everywhere in nature and lots of other stuff. That is why I would like to reread it - because I have forgotten most of it.

Comment: Hey, welcome, nice to see you over here as well! :-) I hope the info you've provided will be enough for someone to find it, but you might also want to have a quick look through [the checklist here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to see if anything jogs your memory of more details. (The standard for story-ID questions is similar to the standard for riddles on PSE: the question needs to have enough info to **uniquely** identify the story.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, unfortunately, I do not remember much - and I have tried finding the book on my own for several years now. I have foolishly given it to a "so-called-friend" and she wouldn't even answer now to at least give me the name and author, let alone return the book. Let's just say, if asked about a reliable person - wouldn't think of her. :) I have tried "ransacking" google and bookstores to no avail. So you (the community here) are my last hope. :)

Comment: I've been hunting around for this, but still unsure what *type* of book to look for. Was it a fiction novel (e.g. in the *Da Vinci Code* genre), or a popular science book such as [this one](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/P/bo23519431.html), or an outside-the-box investigation of unexplained phenomena like one of [Lyall Watson's books](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/525843.Supernature)?

Comment: It is more like a hypothesis type book based on real facts and maybe something like annals? Not much of an investigation - just some observations. PS. I sent an email to the lady again - not sure if she would answer, though and I no longer have any other contact details of her...

Answer (score -1):

Possibly:

> The Da Vinci Code by Dan Brown

which centers on a religious controversy but the characters discuss Fibonacci sequences and the golden ratio etc. appearing in nature so I can imagine references to hexagonal patterns occurring although I read it many years ago and don’t recall the specifics.

The author’s name is short (Dan) and the main character’s name is actually Robert, the name mentioned in the question.

Comment: And it was released 14 years ago, making it a newish, famous-book-of-the-time book around the time OP read it, 13 years ago.

Comment: Nope, it is not that. It is not a famous book, and the book titles suggested until now are translated the same in Bulgarian. That is - none of them references Delphi oracles.